# Differences setTimeout () with setTimeout () in setTimeout ()

Tags: javascript, dependency-injection, settimeout

what anyone could help me, I want to know the difference of:

```
setTimeout ("move ()", 3000);
```

with:

```
setTimeout (function () {setTimeout ("move", 3000)}, 100);
```

thanks to my friends who petrified answer.

Comment: Why do you need setTimeout function calling inside setTimeout function?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the most important difference is in the actual useful code that is executed:

```
setTimeout ("move()", 3000); // executes move(); - a function call
setTimeout ("move", 3000); // executes move; - a statement that doesn't do anything
```

The second difference is in when the useful code is executed:

```
setTimeout ("move()", 3000); // move() gets called at T+3000
setTimeout (function () {setTimeout ("move()", 3000)}, 100); // move() gets called at T+3100
```

The last difference is also when the useful code is executed, but it is more subtile. JavaScript is single threaded, with an event loop. Timeouts can be considered events themselves as they participate in the same event loop as regular DOM events.

```
setTimeout (move, 3000);
```

The first code is straight forward. When that line is executed, a call to move is scheduled to be executed **at least** 3000ms after that time. The "at least" is important, because event handlers can be delayed by quite a while after they are supposed to be executed if the JS engine is busy executing other code.

```
setTimeout (function () {setTimeout (move, 3000)}, 100);
```

The second code is roughly the same, the same scheduling as before is scheduled to be executed **at least ** 100ms after that line is encountered.

One example where execution can be delayed is this one:

```
setTimeout (function () {setTimeout (move, 3000)}, 100);
var d = new Date();
while ((new Date()).getTime() - 10000 < d.getTime()) ; // busy wait for 10 seconds
```

As explained before, some code (doesn't matter what) is scheduled to be executed after at least 100ms. For the next 10 seconds however, the browser is busy executing the while. After the 10 seconds pass, the brower is ready to treat other events, like the scheduled code. In total, the move function gets called (at least) 13 seconds after the first call to setTimeout.

To conclude, the differences are subtile and there is nothing that would justify a call to setTimeout inside another call to setTimeout in a simple scenario as above. If the program logic demands it, there is also nothing inherently bad.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question , two difference

First let us define:

- Method A: setTimeout ("move ()", 3000);
- Method B: setTimeout (function () {setTimeout ("move", 3000)}, 100);

**1.Different compile order by javascript vm**

For A javascript try to compile the str into runnable code and run it after 3000 milliseconds, versus B try to compile the the function into runnable code instantly , but run it after 3000 milliseconds.

Try following demo:

```
setTimeout ('alert("A")', 3000); 
// "A" alerted after 3000 milliseconds
setTimeout (alert('B')||function(){alert('C')}, 3000); 
// "B" alerted instantly, while C alerted after 3000 milliseconds
```

**2.Different usage scope**

B can have a larger usage scope, for B can carry any variable for function as context by using closure, but A just only have the context of window or document.

Try following demo:

```
(function(){var va = 1; setTimeout ('alert(va)', 3000)}());
// run into error:Uncaught ReferenceError: va is not defined after 3000 milliseconds
(function(){var vb = 1; setTimeout(function(){alert(vb)}, 3000);}()); 
// 1 alerted after 3000 milliseconds
```